# Нужно дополнить парсер на java

Tags: java, парсер, maven, потоки-данных

Мой код ниже:

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class parser {

    public static String test(Element element, Function<Element, String> function) {
        return function.apply(element);
    }

    private static Document getPars() throws IOException {
        String url = "https://pogoda.mail.ru/prognoz/kemerovo/";
        Document page = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 30000);
        return page;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document page = getPars();
        Element wrapper = page.select("div[class=wrapper]").first();
        Element names = wrapper.select("div[class=days__wrapper]").first();
        Elements allDays = names.select("div[class=day day_index]");
        for (Element days : allDays) {
            System.out.println(days.text());
        }
    }
}
```

Это самый простой парсер для считывания данных о погоде в Кемерово. Хочу дополнить его stream'ами, но не знаю как они работают и для чего вообще нужны. Покажите, пожалуйста, пример их использования.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Comment: если вы никогда не работали со стримами и не понимаете что это, то можете считать их аналогом циклов. с учетом этого возникает вопрос:  какую именно проблему вы хотите решить с помощью стримов, если единственный цикл, который у вас есть , просто выводит результат в консоль?

Comment: Дмитрий, мне выдали домашнее задание, в котором нужно использовать stream для решения любой задачи. А как и что для этого нужно сделать, я не совсем понимаю